# Increment a date with array of days

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Actually my date is  `$Date= '03/02/2015';`

I want to increment this day with array of days .My array is

```
  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 42 [2] => 70 [3] => 98 [4] => 186 [5] => 279 [6] => 372 [7] => 465 [8] => 558 [9] => 730 [10] => 1460 [11] => 4380 [12] => 1825 ).
```

I stored this array in a variable called  `$data`.I want to increment my date with each of this days and print all result dates.How can i do it???

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, can you edit your question and align the text and code up properly, and explain more clearly what is it you want? What have you tried, and what happens?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<?php

$Date= '03/02/2015';
$stamp= strtotime($Date);

$days=array(42,70,98,186,279,372,465,558,730,1460,4380,1825); //change these values
$values=array();
foreach($days as $day){
   $newstamp=$stamp+($day*24*60*60);
   $values[]=date("m/d/Y",$newstamp);
}

//now add to database
mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass'); //change user pass
mysql_select_db('yourdatabase'); //change here

foreach($values as $value) {
    $sql="insert into yourtable values('".$value."',xxx,xxxx..))"; //change here
    mysql_query($sql);
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Actually i want to store this dates in a table so need this values after the loop

Comment: I have changed as per as your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this with this code you can print dates

```
<?php   
    $Date = "2015-02-03";
    $dataArray = Array ( 1 ,42 , 70 , 98 , 186 , 279 ,372);
    foreach($dataArray as $val){
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. " + $val days"))."</br>";
    }
?>
```